# Many to many AQL query

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have 2 collections and one edge collection. USERS, FILES and FILES_USERS.
Im trying to get all FILES documents, that has the field "what" set to "video", for a specific user, but also embed another document, also from the collection FILES, but where the "what" is set to "trailer" and belongs to the "video" into the results.

I have tried the below code but its not working correctly, im getting a lot of duplicate results...its a mess. Im definitely doing it wrong.

```
 FOR f IN files
 FILTER f.what=="video"

 LET trailer = (
    FOR f2 IN files
      FILTER f2.parent_key==f._key
      AND f2.what=="trailer"
      RETURN f2
   )


  FOR x IN files_users
    FILTER x._from=="users/18418062"
    AND x.owner==true
    RETURN DISTINCT {f,trailer}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this with graph query syntax, but try this. Adjust the UNIQUE functions based on your data-model.

```
LET user_files = UNIQUE(FOR u IN FILES_USERS 
                         FILTER u._from == "users/18418062" AND u.owner 
                         RETURN u._to)

FOR uf IN user_files
 FOR f IN files 
 FILTER f._key == uf AND f.what == "video"

 LET trailers = UNIQUE(FOR t IN files 
                        FILTER t.parent_key == f._key AND t.what == "trailer" 
                        RETURN t)

RETURN {"video": f, "trailers": trailers}
```

Comment: this solved it, except it was f._id instead of f._key

Answer (score 1):

Well, check to see If you have duplicate data as suggested by TMan, however check your query syntax too. It appears that you have no link between your f subquery and the x in the main query. That would cause the query to potentially return a lot of dups if there are multiple records in collection files_users for user users/18418062

Try adding a join in the main query. Something like:

```
  FOR x IN files_users
    FILTER x._from=="users/18418062"
    AND x.owner==true
       AND x._to == f._id
    RETURN DISTINCT {f,trailer}
```

On a related note, if you run into performance issues doing a subquery for trailers , you could instead try just doing a join and [array expansion](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Advanced/ArrayOperators.html#array-expansion) and see if that works for your case